# Correct NSString output

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have talbeView that populate data from JSON. One my text label fill itself with `NSString`, and sometimes it output `0(NSNULL)`, which obviously, not suppose to be output on cell text label.

Following code:

```
if ([(cell.myNameLabel.text)  isEqual: @"0(NSNull)"]){
        cell.myNameLabel.text = @"No Name";
    }
```

Isn't work, i wonder why?

How to fix that?

Comment: Try `isEqualToString`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data populated from `JSON` use here like this :

```
//use accordingly that it may contain either NSDictionary or NSArray.
NString *strValue = youJSONDataArray[indexPath.row];

if ([value isEqual:[NSNull null]] || value.length == 0) {
  strValue == @"";
}
```

Set string value in `UILabel` like this:

```
cell.myNameLabel.text = strValue;
```

Comment: Thank you! Now its ok for me ;)

Answer (score 1):

`NSJSONSerialization` uses `NSNull` to indicate a null JSON value.

Try this instead:

```
if ([cell.myNameLabel.text isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {
     // …
}
```

But you'll probably want to strip out the `NSNull`s during parsing so that your code isn't littered with `NSNull` checks.

Answer (score 1):

If a JSON response has a null value then its indicated by `NSNull` by `NSJSONSerialization` class so you can modify your code to

```
if ([cell.myNameLabel.text isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {
 // your logic here
}
```